# How can we create an ExternalLink to data in read-only files using h5py / hdf5?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

We have data in read-only hdf5 files (owned by another user). During data reduction we write results into new hdf5 files. I want to add a link into the results file which points back to the raw data. There is a problem: h5py.ExternalLink appears to try to open the external raw data file with the same file permissions as our results file.

Using h5py I did not figure out how to set up the ExternalLink for a read only dataset within a file that is open for writing (or appending). Do we need to use something like `H5Pset_elink_fapl`, or is this just impossible within hdf5?

Example code is below:

```
import h5py, os, stat, sys

dname = 'target.h5'
if os.path.exists( dname ): 
    os.chmod( dname, stat.S_IRUSR|stat.S_IWUSR )
    os.remove(dname)
    
# create a target file with some data in it:
with h5py.File(dname,"w") as h:
    h['/root/data'] = list(range(20))

# make this file read only
os.chmod( dname, stat.S_IRUSR )

# create a file that links to the read only data
with h5py.File("linker.h5","w") as h:
    h['/root/pointer'] = h5py.ExternalLink( dname, '/root/data' )
    
# Attempt to open and read the data:
for mode in "r", "r+", "a":
    try:
        # now retreive the read only data
        with h5py.File("linker.h5",mode) as h:
            data = h['/root/pointer'][:]
            print( 'mode',mode,data.shape )
    except Exception as e:
        print('mode',mode,'fails', str(e))
        
for obj in "sys.platform sys.version h5py.version.version h5py.version.hdf5_version".split():
    print(obj, ":", eval(obj))
```

Sample outputs:

```
mode r (20,)
mode r+ fails "Unable to open object (unable to open external file, external link file name = 'target.h5')"
mode a fails "Unable to open object (unable to open external file, external link file name = 'target.h5')"
sys.platform : win32
sys.version : 3.9.7 (default, Oct 26 2021, 17:33:26) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
h5py.version.version : 3.6.0
h5py.version.hdf5_version : 1.12.1
```

```
mode r (20,)
mode r+ fails "Unable to open object (unable to open file, file name = 'target.h5', temp_file_name = 'target.h5')"
mode a fails "Unable to open object (unable to open file, file name = 'target.h5', temp_file_name = 'target.h5')"
sys.platform : linux
sys.version : 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
h5py.version.version : 2.10.0
h5py.version.hdf5_version : 1.10.4
```

Comment: Interesting question. I haven't ever locked a HDF5 file as read only at the OS level (although understand why you would want to do this). I suspect it's related to the underlying code that opens the linked file (maybe it inherits the linking file's `mode` parameter for consistency)? I think the h5py/HDF5 developers will have to answer this. Try posting this question and example at their forum: [Latest h5py topics](https://forum.hdfgroup.org/c/hdf-tools/h5py)

Comment: After reading the `H5Pset_elink_fapl` doc, I think you're on the right track. It looks like that's how to open external links in a target file with a different access property than the link file. You could do that if you were using FORTRAN or C. However, it may not be exposed in the h5py package. I can't find any mention in the h5py docs.

Comment: Thanks! I cross posted it in the main hdf5 forum too. There are wrappers in h5py.h5p for `[gs]et_elink_fapl` but I didn't figure out how to call them. A small C-program to fix a file would be a good solution too. Looking at the hdf5 file format, I don't see where this information could get saved into the file?(https://docs.hdfgroup.org/hdf5/develop/_f_m_t3.html#LinkMessage). If this function has to be called every time a file is opened, it might be better to just store filename and dataset and stop trying to use external links !

Comment: You are in uncharted waters. I did more research on `[gs]et_elink_fapl` and `H5Pset_elink_fapl`. I didn't find much (other than the github source for `h5py.h5p`). It's not mentioned on the old h5py Google Forum, and nothing on GitHub. As I understand, you save the link access property in the linked file (with `set_elink_fapl` , then it's used when accessing a linked file. However, you might have to `set_elink_fapl`  before accessing linked files.  If you don't get an answer on the Forum, try h5py on github. (That will get a h5py developer's attention.)

Comment: @jon did you find a way to make this work?

Comment: Also relevant: https://forum.hdfgroup.org/t/virtual-dataset-in-read-write-file-missing-data-from-read-only-file/5647